# How to fix [Error] PLS-00049 (30: 38): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.V_COLUMN'” In Trigger Dinamic Get column

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, audit

I set the trigger audit and send an audit log with loop to a get log column in tables log.

This for Oracle 12c

```
-- Tables
```

`CREATE TABLE DBADMIN.DBLOG_MONITORING_DETAIL2(
      SID      VARCHAR2(999 BYTE),
      COLUMNS   VARCHAR2(999 BYTE),
      OLDVALUE   VARCHAR2(999 BYTE),
      NEWVALUE   VARCHAR2(999 BYTE)
    );

--Trigger

 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TA_EMPLOYEES3
        AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
        ON DBADMIN.EMPLOYEES
        FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        SID   VARCHAR2 (30);
    BEGIN
        SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') INTO IP FROM DUAL;
        SELECT SEQ# INTO SID1 FROM v$session
         WHERE audsid = (SELECT USERENV ('SESSIONID') FROM DUAL);
        IF INSERTING
        THEN
            FOR I IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
                        FROM dba_tab_columns
                       WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEES')
            LOOP N := N + 1;
                v_column := i.COLUMN_NAME;
                INSERT INTO DBADMIN.DBLOG_MONITORING_DETAIL2 (SID,COLUMNS,OLDVALUE, NEWVALUE)
                     VALUES (SID1,
                             i.COLUMN_NAME,
                             :OLD.v_column,
                             :NEW.v_column);
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
    END;
/`

I have error

> [Error] PLS-00049 (31: 26): PLS-00049: bad bind variable
>   'OLD.V_COLUMN'

can help me ?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not possible. You can't dynamically refer to the column names using the `NEW` or `OLD`  pseudo-records. You must explicitly check with actual columns individually if the the old and new values have changed and insert rows for each into your `DBLOG_MONITORING_DETAIL2` table.

Comment: what can I do for that to be possible ??
use store procedure or what? can u help mee ??
because the update for the table is very intense. can occur every month ..
and I don't know what changes if there are changes

Comment: I did mention a possible solution in my comment..

Comment: Logging changes at the column level is a common audit anti-pattern. The only efficient way to do things is to have a audit table whose projection aligns with the transaction table. The best approach is to use Oracle Flashback Data Archive, which automatically builds journalling tables and infrastructure for us. [Find out more](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/a-fresh-look-at-auditing-row-changes)

Comment: Thank u all .. 
now i change my plan, better using stored procedures to create triggers, with the intention that the App / user executes these stored procedures to generate automatic drop replace triggers.

Comment: now i confused create trigger using store procedure . can u help me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456328/create-trigger-with-stored-procedures-by-making-dynamic-in-the-trigger-column