# Create Trigger with stored procedures by making dynamic in the trigger column

Tags: linux, database, oracle, oracle12c

Im create new trigger audit using store procedure cause want flexible column in the trigger audit

im using Oracle 12 C ..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBADMIN.TEST3 (OUTPUT          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                          TABLE_NAME   IN     VARCHAR2)
IS
    N   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    N := 0;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DBADMIN.TA_EMPLOYEES3
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
    ON DBADMIN.EMPLOYEES
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    SID   VARCHAR2 (30);
BEGIN
    SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('' USERENV       '', ''    IP_ADDRESS          '') INTO IP FROM DUAL;

    SELECT SEQ#
      INTO SID1
      FROM v$session
     WHERE audsid = (SELECT USERENV ('' SESSIONID '') FROM DUAL);

    IF INSERTING
    THEN
        INSERT INTO DBADMIN.DBLOG_MONITORING_DETAIL2 (SID,
                                                          COLUMNS,
                                                          OLDVALUE,
                                                          NEWVALUE)
                 VALUES (SID1,
                         i.COLUMN_NAME,
                        'for row in (SELECT column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name=''EMPLOYEES'' loop  
                        execute immediate '':old.row.column_name '';
                      end loop;
/
```

> 32    26  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR"

i think im bad logic in my script .. can give me better logic or repair my script its better ?? .

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you should really rarely use dynamic SQL to create database objects. People sometimes abuse that functionality which is - in my opinion - what you're trying to do. The fact that you *can* do it doesn't mean that you *should* do it, e.g. you can poke your eye with a pencil, but you shouldn't do that.

Rule of thumb with dynamic SQL:

- forget about `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`
- Create a local variable (a large `VARCHAR2` or `CLOB`, depending on what you're doing)
- compose the statement (`CREATE TRIGGER` in your case) and
- store it into that variable
- display it on the screen using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`
- copy/paste it and run it as a standalone statement

  - if it succeeds, you've done a good job so you can now use it in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`
  - if it fails, you'll have to try a little bit harder, debug it, fix errors and repeat the cycle

As of the error you got: this:

```
for row in (SELECT column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name=''EMPLOYEES'' loop  
  execute immediate '':old.row.column_name '';
end loop;
```

is invalid as the `INSERT INTO` target; you can't mix SQL and PL/SQL that way. It won't work at all, regardless dynamic SQL you use. Besides, it is obvious that it is wrong (missing closing bracket, what exactly are you *executing immediately*? `old_row.column_name`? How would you *execute* a column name?

In my opinion (once again), you shouldn't do it that way. If you want to create a trigger, do it - but **not** *dynamically*.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I just want to do dynamic creation of the column because it is a user requirement. btw what should I do on the loop to retrieve the data column ??